# How to select only the characters appearing before a specific symbol in a SQL Select statement

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I have strings in a database like this:

```
firstname.lastname@domain.com
```

And I only need the characters that appear before the @ symbol.

I am trying to find a simple way to do this in SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to get the value before the @ character, you'll need to use something like:

```
SELECT LEFT(Email, CHARINDEX('@',Email)-1) FIELD_ALIAS FROM YOUR_DE
```

Replace the `FIELD_ALIAS` with the name of the field where you want to store this value. Also, replace `Email` with the field from where you'll be getting the emails..

Basically, we are using the [LEFT](https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [CHARINDEX](https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) functions of SQL Server.

`CHARINDEX('@',Email)` will return the index of the @ character. And since we don't want to get this character, we need to substract 1 from it.

`LEFT` will return all characters to the left of the @ character.